# Validation message doesn't appear in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, validationmessage

I am using ASP.NET MVC for form validation. I have one page of "**Users**" which have two forms named as "**adduser**" form and "**edituser**" form.I'm trying to apply same validation message against `m.user.firstName` property for both forms.

Add user form:

```
<form id="addUserForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.user.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control-modal", @id = "fNameEditVal" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.user.FirstName, "")
</form>
```

Edit user form:

```
<form id="editUserForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.user.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control-modal", @placeholder = "", @id = "fNameAddVal", @required = "required"  })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.user.FirstName, "")
</form>
```

But when I submit the form of add user without writing any text in that field it properly shows the validation message "Please enter your first name " but when I submit the edit user form it will not show any message. When I change `@Html.TextBoxFor` to `@Html.EditorFor`, the message is showing up perfectly.

Comment: You cannot have 2 `TextBoxFor()` for the same property - the 2nd will not have the `data-val-*` attributes necessary for client side validation. And you `@required = "required"` makes no sense (that is ignored when using mvc client side validation using `jquury.validate`. But your view makes no sense. You can only submit one form so what is the point of 2 forms - all you doing is degrading performance

Comment: if i want to add new user than i m using add user form if i want to edit user than i m using edit user form. but they both forms are in modal popup which appears when u click on button add user or edit user.

Comment: Use the same form! (you can either post back to a single `Edit` method, and check the `Id` value to determine if its a new user or existing user, of you could conditionally change the forms action attribute based on which button was clicked)

Comment: is there any solution for this to apply validation on that property without changing these two forms into one.

Comment: Why in the world would you want to duplicate all the html and have 2 forms - that is just crazy.

Comment: Yes, you are right. i should use one form for add and edit. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a restructure of the page(s) as you can't have 2 text boxes for the same property (as Stephen suggested).

I would have the following:

- a `Partial View` with the common form fields (`TextBoxFor` etc) between add and edit.
- a `View for add` (this can be a pop up) which is strongly typed to your model, includes the validatiin JS scripts etc and includes your form `Partial View`
- a `View for edit` (again, to be used in the pop up) which is strongly typed to your model, includes the validatiin JS scripts etc and includes your form `Partial View`. In addition, this would have a `Hidden` field for the `Id` (or whatever your primary key is for the object)

...then, depending on what you are doing you would call the add or edit action via JS for your pop up.